# I need help identifying an IC marked LDBX - N504 - 108

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, switching-regulator

***DISCLAIMER***
I'm not an engineer
***DISCLAIMEREND***

I'm trying to repair a custom PCB that runs a controller for a Tesla coil. All controller functions are operated by a CY8C58LP PSoC.

[Link to datasheet for PSoC](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-PSoC_5LP_CY8C58LP_Family_Datasheet_Programmable_System-on-Chip_(PSoC_)-DataSheet-v15_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0ec547013ab9)

The circuit is powered by 5VDC throug USB-C. The IC in question appears to be a 10-pin DFN nonlinear regulator. I've tested all the passive components around the circuit, and if I bypass the regulator with a bench-top power supply, the controller turns on and functions.

I've been looking at several options for replacing the regulator, but the layout of this specific chip seems unique. I've made a small diagram that should be posted below:

[image: ICLayout]

Comment: Disclaimer I’m not a psychic end disclaimer. It would help if you posted a picture of said device. Sometimes hints can be got to narrow down the search.

Comment: The topology in the schematic looks like a buck converter (step-down switch-mode converter).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like LTC4081. The datasheet indicates Part marking of "LDBX" here https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4081fa.pdf

Comment: This was it! Part came in yesterday and I just installed it. Controller is once again in working order. Thank you very much!